# Execute Query on a Specific Date and Time

Tags: php, sql

Is there a possible way to execute a query on a specific given Date and Time using PHP or ODBC

```
$date = '11/30/2013 11:59 AM';
```

```sql
Insert into tbl1 (id,name,age) values ('$id','$name','$age');
```

Comment: use cron job for this purpose.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman tnx man, ill look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software utility CRON is something that can help you schedule jobs and this is generally found in Unix based operating Systems. So if you are using some Unix based hosting, they maybe providing you a scheduler that can help you execute a particular PHP script at a particular interval.

This is the link to [BlueHost](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/168) page that tells you ways to set up CRON with your PHP. Similarly you can find ways to do this at your own hosting. I am sure there is not a lot of programming involved, just you need to make sure how can you initialize CRON at your server or hosting and then you can write your PHP scripts in normal fashion (like you always do)

One thing more, if your hosting is providing you Cpanel (which most hostings do these days), [this link](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs) might then be helpful for you. Happy Scheduling :)

Comment: can i use it in Windows Operating System?

Comment: Yes there is a Task Scheduler in the windows as well. I have not used it but I am sure it can run PHP scripts for you as well. Take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569. This may help you in achieving with windows.