# How can I receive a notification whenever there are record in a database table?

Tags: database, codeigniter

How do I get a notification whenever there is a record in a particular table in the database?

1. If I use a Trigger in MySQL will not work when I change database.
2. If I make an Ajax request every certain interval, I will make unnecessary requests and I've been punished for it in Hostmonster (escape them).
3. Another idea?

> This guy went through the problem as me:
>   http://www.schiffner.com/11-excruciating-months-with-hostmonster-have-come-to-an-end/

Thank you.

Comment: Use ajax and skip the shitty host.

Comment: Thank you OneOfOne. I hate Hostmonster... :(

Comment: Use AJAX, make interval high enough (1 minute or 30 seconds) also create button for manual refreshing and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending Ajax requests at regular intervals **(long polling)** may not be the best solution but I have seen this implementation in many applications and probably it is easy to implement.

One of the solutions that has not been mentioned here is a PHP script running in a scheduler. This question will help you and make things clearer. [Schedule alarm notification system php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368901/schedule-alarm-notification-system-php/20369147#20369147)

Do let me know if you need more info.

Comment: added information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/html5-websocket-vs-long-polling-vs-ajax